# Showing $|\int\frac{e^{2z}}{1+e^z}\,dz|\leq\frac{2\pi e^{2R}}{e^R-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Show that

$$
\left|\int_c \frac{e^{2z}}{1+e^z}\,dz \right|\leq \frac{2\pi e^{2R}}{e^{R}-1}
$$

where $c$ is the vertical line segment from $z=R, (R>0)$ to $z=R+2\pi i $.

The answer tells me that the integral is less than
$$\int_c \frac{e^{2x}}{e^x-1}\,dx$$ and then just evaluate it but I don't understand how they get there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $|e^z|=e^{\text{Re}\,z}$ and $|e^z+1|\geq|e^z|-1=e^{\text{Re}\,z}-1$. Now apply some basic inequalities on the integrand using these estimates.

Comment: $ |e^z+1|≥|e^z|−1=e^{Re z}−1 $

How do you motivate that?

Comment: @Danny: Triangle inequality.

Comment: I'm feeling abit slow here because i don't understand that part.